# overload new and delete operator

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a small doubt. I don't know whether my question is valid or not but i am putting it in SO.
First Question:
when we overload the operator new and operator delete(not for arrays) at global or class level  and then if we crate an array of objects something like below:

```
A* obj = new A[10];
delete []obj;
```

then in that case why it is calling the operator new and delete even though i have not overloaded for the arrays i.e. i have not overloaded like below

```
void* operator new[](size_t size){}
```

Second Question:
But if i overload the new and delete operator for arrays like above then it will call the one having array syntax.

Last but not the least, if i don't overload the new and delete operator at all, then which one will be called when i create an array of objects. Is it the one array syntax or normal one.
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `new T[n]`, the memory is allocated by `operator
new[]( size_t )`.  If you replace this function, then your
replacement will be called.  If you don't replace this function,
the default implementation will be called, which is, by
definition:

```
void*
operator new[]( size_t n )
{
    return operator new( n );
}
```

In other words, it forwards to the non-array `operator new`
function.  Thus, if you've replaced `operator new()`, your
replacement will be called.

(But why are you doing a `new []`?  I've never found a case
where it would be useful.)

Comment: So this means we don't need to overload `new[]` at all if it would just do the same as `new` anyway, interesting to know. Is this delegation by-standard or just the most common implementation of the default `new[]`?

Comment: *"(But why are you doing a new []? I've never found a case where it would be useful.)"* - Uh, maybe just to test his overloaded `new`-operators and see that it behaves strangely (from his point of view)? Or to provide an SSCCE for the question?

Comment: @ChristianRau This is required by the standard.  You only need to overload `operator new[]()` if you want it to have different behavior (e.g. if a member `operator new()` is allocating from a pool, and starts with `assert(size == sizeof(T));`).

Comment: I am not using anywhere just for a knowledge i asked